# I need to recursively change the percentage width of a progress bar in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what i have so far and it doenst work... the bar doenst move at all! So the bar its barraturbo. Please help me Thanks in advance

```
setInterval(function(){
        if(barraTurbo.width>'60%' && barraTurbo.width<'100%'){
            barraTurbo.className="green";
            barraTurbo.width-='1%';
            turbobarra-=1;
            document.getElementById("spanTurbo").innerHTML=turbobarra;
        }
        if(barraTurbo.width<'60%' && barraTurbo.width>'20%'){
            barraTurbo.className="orange";
            barraTurbo.width-='1%';
            turbobarra-=1;
            document.getElementById("spanTurbo").innerHTML=turbobarra;
        }
        if(barraTurbo.width<'20%' && barraTurbo.width>'0%'){
            barraTurbo.className="red";
            barraTurbo.width-='1%';
            turbobarra-=1;
            document.getElementById("spanTurbo").innerHTML=turbobarra;
        }
        if(barraTurbo.width=='0%'){
            document.onkeydown = funcionamentoSetaFuncionalidades;
        }
    },500);
```

Comment: Do you really mean "recursively"?

Comment: well maybe not, i just wanted to keep removing its width till it got to 0%

Comment: what `bar` you using?

Comment: A _string_ comparison for `>'60%'` and `<'100%'` makes little sense – because strings are compared character-by-character from left to right, so `60%` is a _greater_ value than `100%`.

Comment: im using something i found online, ill see if i can find the link

Comment: http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/multi-colored-progress-bars

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the max value and min value:

```
setInterval(function(){
        if(barraTurbo.width>'100%' && barraTurbo.width<'60%'){
            barraTurbo.className="green";
            barraTurbo.width-='1%';
            turbobarra-=1;
            document.getElementById("spanTurbo").innerHTML=turbobarra;
        }
        if(barraTurbo.width<'20%' && barraTurbo.width>'60%'){
            barraTurbo.className="orange";
            barraTurbo.width-='1%';
            turbobarra-=1;
            document.getElementById("spanTurbo").innerHTML=turbobarra;
        }
        if(barraTurbo.width<'0%' && barraTurbo.width>'20%'){
            barraTurbo.className="red";
            barraTurbo.width-='1%';
            turbobarra-=1;
            document.getElementById("spanTurbo").innerHTML=turbobarra;
        }
        if(barraTurbo.width=='0%'){
            document.onkeydown = funcionamentoSetaFuncionalidades;
        }
    },500);
```